# Existence of a ring automorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ring-theory

Let $A$ be a commutative ring, $B$ a commutative ring that is also an  $A$-algebra of finite presentation. Let $f_1$ and $f_2$ be two elements of $B$ such that $(f_1) + (f_2) = B$ and as $A$-modules, $$B=A \oplus f_1 B \quad ; \quad B=A \oplus f_2 B.$$

In which cases do you know that there exists an $A$-automorphism of rings $\psi : B \to B$ such that $\psi(f_1) = f_2$ and $\psi(f_2) = f_1$ ?

Comment: Please clarify the categories with which you work. Does $B = A \oplus f_1 B$ refer to the underlying $A$-modules? Is $\phi$ an automorphism of the $A$-algebra $B$?

Comment: Yes. And I would like to know if such a $\psi$ exists.

Comment: Please edit the question to include *all* relevant information.

Comment: Are $A,B$ commutative? What about other finiteness assumptions, for example is $A$ noetherian? Are $f_1,f_2$ regular?

Comment: $\rm A$ and $\rm B$ commutative yes but not noetherian. If you can say something in the case where $f_1$ and $f_2$ are regular, it is nice.

Comment: Keep adding the relevant information to the main question!

Comment: Damien, have you seen my answer? ;)

Comment: It doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Well it answers the original question ("Is there an automorphism" instead "In which cases is there an automorphism").

Answer (score 1):

A special case of this question with an algebro-geometric flavor is the following: Let $k$ be a field and let $X$ be an affine algebraic scheme over $k$. Does $\mathrm{Aut}(X)$ act transitively on the $k$-rational points of $X$ which correspond to principal maximal ideals? But this is far from being true since automorphisms preserve the local rings, which can be regular or not. A simple counterexample is given by $X = \mathrm{Spec}(k) \sqcup \mathrm{Spec}(k[\varepsilon]/\varepsilon^2)$. In purely algebraic terms and with the notation of the question, this means $A=k$, $B=k \times k[\varepsilon]/\epsilon^2$, $f_1=(0,1)$, $f_2 = (1,\varepsilon)$.